# Compare-Object Not Comparing Each Element of Array

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I am attempting to use `Compare-Object` to find elements that are in one array (`$fileArray`) but not in another (`$dictionaryArray`). For some reason, `Compare-Object` is only comparing the last two elements in fileArray. Here is the code I am trying to run.

```
$dictionary = Get-Content "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\PowerShell Scripts\Work\PCI Numbers\dictionary.txt"
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\PowerShell Scripts\Work\PCI Numbers\file.txt"

$dictionaryArray = @()
$fileArray = @()

$dictionaryLength = $dictionary | Measure-Object -Line
$fileLength = $file | Measure-Object -Line

$i = 0

while($i -lt $dictionaryLength.Lines){
    $name = $dictionary | Select -Index $i
    $i++
    while($dictionary[$i] -ne " " -and $i -lt $dictionaryLength.Lines){
        $dictionaryObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $dictionaryObject | Add-Member -Name 'PC' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $name
        $dictionaryObject | Add-Member -Name 'File' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $dictionary[$i]
        $dictionaryArray += $dictionaryObject
        $i++
    }
    $i++
}

$i = 0

while($i -lt $fileLength.Lines){
    $name = $file | Select -Index $i
    $i++
    while($file[$i] -ne " " -and $i -lt $fileLength.Lines){
        $fileObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $fileObject | Add-Member -Name 'PC' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $name
        $fileObject | Add-Member -Name 'File' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $file[$i]
        $fileArray += $fileObject
        $i++
    }
    $i++
}

$i = 0

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fileArray -DifferenceObject $dictionaryArray |
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} |
    ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_.InputObject}
```

When I simply run `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fileArray
-DifferenceObject $dictionaryArray`, I get the output

```
InputObject                                          SideIndicator
@{PC=Joe; File=nopethere}                            &lt;=
@{PC=Joe; File=hi!!!@}                               &lt;=
```

There are more items than this in the fileArray. When I run `$fileArray`, I get

```
PC             File
Eric           I like to
Eric           there
Joe            code because
Joe            hello
Joe            but why?
Joe            *no\thank/ you :c
Joe            nopethere
Joe            hi!!!@
```

Why is my code not comparing each one of these objects?

**EDIT**

Here is dictionary.txt

```
Eric
because
hello there

Joe
but why?
*no\thank/ you :c
nope
```

Here is file.txt

```
Eric
I like to
there

Joe
code because
hello
but why?
*no\thank/ you :c
nopethere
hi!!!@
```

I use my loop to create objects. The first line of each paragraph is the "PC" for each subsequent object. Then, each line is the "File" of each object. I want to check which objects are in fileArray and not in dictionaryArray. I would expect the output to be

```
PC             File
Eric           I like to
Joe            code because
Joe            hello
Joe            nopethere
Joe            hi!!!@
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Without knowing the content of dicitionary.txt/array it's difficult to give a hint. Your code seems overcomplicatef to me, why not use a `ForEach($Item in $dictionary){..}` to iterate `$dictionary`

Comment: Please provide sample input and describe not only the result you're getting, but also the result you were expecting.

Comment: This looks like a bit of an XY problem - can you perhaps describe 1) what the contents of the txt files look like, and 2) what you're trying to accomplish with your script - looks like you might be over-complicating things a bit here